# Why do some Windows commands produce output when run as a CGI script and others don't?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, output, cgi

I'm developing a web app on Windows 7 with Apache 2.4.23. I have a very simple CGI script, which is implemented as a Windows `cmd` batch file. For some commands invoked from the batch file, like `type`, the output gets served to the client. For others, e.g. `sort`, it disappears in nirvana.

Here is an example code of my CGI script:

```dos
@echo off
echo Content-Type: text/plain

echo.
echo ---Start---
type some.txt
echo ----End----
```

which nicely shows the contents of `some.txt` in the browser, surrounded by the `Start` and `End` tags. However, simply replacing `type` with `sort` results in no output. The `Start` and `End` tags are still shown, as expected, but nothing between them. Curiously, both `type` and `sort` work well (that is, show their output on the console) when invoked from the command line on the server.

What might be going on here?

For completeness: When I invoke the commands from a Perl CGI script, they both work fine.

Comment: `echo` and `type` are internal commands of `cmd.exe`, but `sort` is a console application. The console application is `sort.exe` located in `%SystemRoot%\System32`. I suppose that either `sort.exe` is not found on running the batch file via Apache or a different `sort.*` is found and executed. That depends on environment variables `PATH` and `PATHEXT` as defined on running the batch file via Apache. I suggest to specify in batch file `%SystemRoot%\System32\sort.exe` and check if you get now the expected output. And you might add `set PATH` or just `set` to get output the environment variables.

Comment: @Mofi: Thanks for the suggestion, but specyfing the full path also doesn't help. In the real app I actually run a different `exe` which I specify with the full path anyway. If I don't, I get an error message, not an empty output.

Comment: Perhaps your real application does not output to handle __STDOUT__, but for example to __STDERR__. And output to __STDERR__ is not captured by Apache. Run your real application with `"Path to\real app\app.exe" 2>&1` as Microsoft explains in article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) to get text written to __STDERR__ redirected to __STDOUT__.

Comment: Applications can also be designed to write data to the console, bypassing redirection altogether.

Comment: @Mofi & Harry Johnston: No, it outputs the output to `stdout` and errors to `stderr`, just as it should. Even if it didn't, it wouldn't explain the `sort` (mis)behavior, or the proper behavior when invoked from Perl.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't help further on this issue as it is impossible for me to reproduce this problem.